# Netty Channel Input from different source than socket

Tags: netty

I'd like use a different input than a socket for the Netty handler. Is this possible? If so what would be a valid input format?

Answer (score 0):

You could either write your own `Channel` implementation or use `EmbeddedChannel` which allows you to use `writeInbound(..)` to feed it with data.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I cant :/ "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." thats the message i get when i try to give you an upvote. Maybe i can come back to it later when i have more then 15 reputation.